Unable to verify smart contract on ApeChain Curtis Testnet using Forge/Foundry
Problem Description
I'm trying to verify a smart contract on ApeChain Curtis testnet (chain ID: 33111) using Forge/Foundry. While the deployment works successfully, I'm encountering verification issues despite trying multiple approaches.
What I've Tried
Approach 1: Combined Deploy and Verify
forge script script/DeployNFTMintDN404.s.sol:DeployNFTMintDN404 \
    --rpc-url $CURTIS_RPC_URL \
    --private-key $DEPLOYER_KEY \
    --etherscan-api-key $APECHAIN_API_KEY \
    --broadcast \
    --verify \
    --verifier blockscout \
    --verifier-url "https://api.apescan.io/api" \
    --chain-id 33111 \
    -vvvv

Error received:
Start verification for (2) contracts
Start verifying contract `0xc0946Eb595274B7Ff5fD52750ff9eA7f9bF7BB8a` deployed on 33111
Submitting verification for [src/example/NFTMintDN404.sol:NFTMintDN404] 0xc0946Eb595274B7Ff5fD52750ff9eA7f9bF7BB8a.
[Multiple submission attempts...]
Transactions saved to: /home/aedjoel/SMDev/Learning/foundry-23/dn404/dn404/broadcast/DeployNFTMintDN404.s.sol/33111/run-latest.json
Sensitive values saved to: /home/aedjoel/SMDev/Learning/foundry-23/dn404/dn404/cache/DeployNFTMintDN404.s.sol/33111/run-latest.json
Error: Etherscan could not detect the deployment.

Approach 2: Separate Deploy and Verify
First deployment:
forge script script/DeployNFTMintDN404.s.sol:DeployNFTMintDN404 \
    --rpc-url $CURTIS_RPC_URL \
    --private-key $DEPLOYER_KEY \
    --broadcast \
    -vvvv

Then verification:
forge script script/DeployNFTMintDN404.s.sol:DeployNFTMintDN404 \
    --rpc-url $CURTIS_RPC_URL \
    --verify \
    --verifier blockscout \
    --verifier-url "https://api.apescan.io/api?apikey=$APECHAIN_API_KEY" \
    --chain-id 33111 \
    --resume \
    -vvvv

Error received:
No associated wallet for addresses: [0x3cc42f45fe6a9a627a94d74ade366d4f77783987]. Unlocked wallets: []

Configuration
My foundry.toml includes:
[rpc_endpoints]
curtis = "${CURTIS_RPC_URL}"

[etherscan]
curtis = { key = "${APECHAIN_API_KEY}", url = "https://api.apescan.io/api" }

Environment Details

Forge/Foundry version: [Please add your version]
Contract successfully deploys to ApeChain Curtis testnet
All environment variables are properly set and validated
The same deployment and verification process works successfully on Sepolia testnet

Questions

Is there a specific configuration needed for ApeChain's Blockscout explorer that differs from standard Etherscan verification?
Are there any known issues with contract verification on ApeChain Curtis testnet using Forge?
Is there an alternative approach to verify contracts on ApeChain that would work better?

Additional Context

The contract deployment itself is successful
The API key is valid and works for other operations on ApeScan
I've tried both with and without including the API key in the verifier URL
I've attempted various delays between deployment and verification
The same process works perfectly on Sepolia testnet

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

The contract verification works correctly on sepolta but not on ape chain…

The API url for the testnet should be like https://api-curtis.apescan.io/api, but they're not showing any API url corresponding to the testnet in their docs.

After the contract deployment, if you run forge verify-contract ${CONTRACT_ADDRESS} src/ContractFilename.sol:ContractName --chain 33111, then it's showing the output as Submitted contract for verification: Response: OK, GUID: 'YOUR_GUID', URL: https://api-curtis.apescan.io/address/${CONTRACT_ADDRESS}. But, still on visiting the explorer, the contract isn't verified.

So, I think you can contact them via their Discord or so, and ask about the exact API endpoint for verification on testnet.
